# I am using Window.onpopstate method in ajax for SPA

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I am using `Window.onpopstate` method in ajax for SPA, before that I used `window.history` but I got an error like

> "jquery-1.10.2.js:8720 Failed to load location:
>   http://localhost:22102/Coach/AddCoaches, state:
>   {"url":"/Coach/AddCoaches"}: Cross origin requests are only supported
>   for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https."

my ajax call is

```
<script>
    $('#loadingImage').hide();
    $('.jq-navigation-link').click(function () {
        var url = $(this).data('url');

        loadPartial(url)

    })
    function loadPartial(url)
    {

        $('#renderPartial').html("");
        $('#loadingImage').show();
        $.ajax({
            url: url + "?ispartial=" + true,
            type: "GET",
            success: function (data) {

                $('#loadingImage').hide();
                $('#renderPartial').html(data);
            }
        })

        window.history.pushState({ url: url }, '', url);
    }
    window.onpopstate = function (event) {
        debugger
        if (event.state) {
            var url = "location: " + document.location + ", state: " + JSON.stringify(event.state);
            load(url);
        }


    };

</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('body').delegate(".btnUrl", "click", function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();
        var url = $('.btnUrl').data('url');
        //var test = $('.form').serialize();
        $('#loadingImage').show();
        $.ajax({
            async: true,
            url: url,
            type: 'POST',
            data: $('.form').serialize(),
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {


                if (data.Success) {
                    $('#loadingImage').hide();
                    loadPartial(data.Url);
                }
                else {
                    $('#loadingImage').hide();
                    loadPartial(data.Url);
                }
            }
        })
    })
    function load(url) {

        $('#renderPartial').html("");
        $('#loadingImage').show();
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "GET",
            success: function (data) {

                $('#loadingImage').hide();
                $('#renderPartial').html(data);
            }
        })


    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Error clearly says it is Cross origin requests. Your Web application is using port 8720 and you web API is using port 22102. Browser is considering requests as different origin and for security reason is blocking data for another site request.

For resolving this, you need to **enable CORS** on your application **OR** need to **host Web application & Web API at same port** or same IIS application.

For Enabling cors try:

1. install nuget package:

   Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors
2. In `App_Start/WebApiConfig.cs`, add following code in Register method before map routing :

   config.EnableCors();
3. In API Controller, `[EnableCors]` attribute to the class:

   `[EnableCors(origins: "http://yoursitehere", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
   public class TestController : ApiController
   {
       // Controller methods not shown...
   }`

OR 
Adding the header through web.config

```
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <clear />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
```

For more details refer:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api

https://forums.asp.net/post/5795304.aspx

Comment: For MVC can I do the same thing?

Comment: Refer second link, for MVC that can be done at both request level or at web config level

Comment: After Adding  <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <clear />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>

Comment: If your webapi & webapp project is different?

Comment: I am using MVC not web Api

Comment: If there is only MVC application then there should not be two ports. Please note jquery ajax request is executing via port 8720 & Controller action method is using port 22102. Something is wrong in application